# Validate character amount, text length and decimal places from input using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I am using a javascript to validate input from a textbox that's inside a ASPxGridView control(DevExpress component).

I am using this javascript code to validate it(thru OnKeyPress event):

```
function CheckKey(s, e) {
    var key = ASPxClientUtils.GetKeyCode(e.htmlEvent);
    var char = String.fromCharCode(key);
    if (e.htmlEvent.shiftKey) {
        if (!IsAvailableChar(char))
            ASPxClientUtils.PreventEvent(e.htmlEvent);
    } else
        if (!(IsAvailableChar(char) || IsAvailableKey(key))) ASPxClientUtils.PreventEvent(e.htmlEvent);

    return;
}

function IsAvailableChar(char) {
    var AvailableChars = "0123456789,";
    return AvailableChars.indexOf(char) != -1;
}

function IsAvailableKey(key) {

    switch (key) {
        case 46: //delete
            return true;
            break;
        case 37: //left arrow
            return true;
            break;
        case 39: //right arrow
            return true;
            break;
        case 16: //shift
            return true;
            break;
        case 188: //comma
            return true;
            break;
        default:
            return false;
            break;
    }
```

I use this to "block" some characters and it works fine.
But now I wanna do something a little bit more complicated: I don't want the user to input more than one comma in the textbox.

A little bit more complicated than that: the maxlength of this textbox is 6. I want it to allow two decimal places only and the maximum of three numbers before the decimal places.
For example:
I want it to allow these strings: "123,12", "45,32", "7,65", "9,6", "85,32", "94,1", "310,2".
I don't want it to allow these strings: "1,123", "125,789", "1234,2"

Any ideas on how I can do that?

Thank you!

**Edit:**

I tried to use the two regular expressions you guys told me to like this:

```
function CheckKey(s, e) {
    var key = ASPxClientUtils.GetKeyCode(e.htmlEvent);
    var char = String.fromCharCode(key);

    var text = document.getElementsByName(s.uniqueID)[0].value + char;

    var regEx = new RegExp("/^\d{0,3}(,\d{0,2})?$/");

    if(regEx.test(text))
        return;
    else
        ASPxClientUtils.PreventEvent(e.htmlEvent);

    return;
}
```

However, `regEx.test(text)` is always returning false, even when the input matches the regular expression.

**Another edit:**

I changed the instantiation of the RegExp object in the code above from this:

```
var regEx = new RegExp("/^\d{0,3}(,\d{0,2})?$/");
```

To this:

```
var regEx = /^\d{0,3}(,\d{0,2})?$/
```

And now it worked, thank you!

Comment: do `console.log(text)` right after you create text, and post us that result.

Comment: Also include the actual contents of the box at the time of the event.

Comment: Not needed, I update the question with what I did to make it work. Thank you! (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^\d{0,3}(,\d{0,2})?$/.test(textbox.value + char);
```

This will match any number with as many as three pre-decimal places.  Optionally, it allows a decimal and up to 2 decimal places.  Also matches the empty string, for ease of use.  So this will check to make sure the resultant box matches.

An explanation of the regEx:

```
^
```

Start of string

```
\d{0,3}
```

0 to 3 digits (inclusive)

```
(...)?
```

An optional group

```
,\d{0,2}
```

A comma followed by 0 to 2 digits (inclusive)

```
$
```

End of string.

Answer (score 1):

```
var regex_test = /^[1-9][0-9]{0,2},[0-9][0-9]{0,1}$/;
var string = '766,99';

if(regex_test.test(string)){
    console.log('good');
}
```

Comment: This would work for after the fact validation, but I think OP is looking for dynamic validation.